# How to increase heap memory size for IE application in windows?

Tags: java, windows, internet-explorer, heap-memory

I am runnning java application in IE but its very slow because of less heap size.
How can I increase heap size for IE alone so that appliaction would run in IE fastly ?
Is there any environmental variable should I change or any other solution please ?

Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applet: Java heap space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026376/applet-java-heap-space)

Answer (score -3):

How To:

1. Close all other applications and programs. Launch Internet Explorer.
2. Choose "Tools" in the main menu bar along the top of the window.
3. Scroll down and click "Internet Options."
4. Using the "General" tab, choose the "Settings " button. It's in either the Temporary Internet Files or the Browsing History section, depending on the version of Internet Explorer you are using.
5. Use the slider to increase the amount of memory allocated to Internet Explorer. Or, on some versions of the browser, use the small "up" arrow in the field next to "Disk Space." You can also change the number in the field, increasing the amount of disk space used.
6. Click the "OK" button, and then click "OK" again. Restart your browser.

Comment: I think you need to learn the difference between heap memory(which is ram) and hard disk memory, you are clearly showing here how to increase disk usage, as if you didn't even read the original question.